# How to substract two column in pandas with condition

Tags: pandas

I have df below

```
Country    Val1 Val2
Australia  4      7
Bambua     23     44
Tambua     24     2
```

How to substract two column

- df['Val1'] - df['Val2'] if Val1 is greater than 'Val2'
- df['Val2'] - df['Val1'] if Val2 is greater than 'Val1'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also just compute the absolute value:

```
pdf['diff'] = np.abs(pdf.Val1 - pdf.Val2)
```

```
     Country  Val1  Val2  diff
0  Australia     4     7     3
1     Bambua    23    44    21
2     Tambua    24     2    22
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['new'] = np.where(df['Val1'] > df['Val2'], 
                     df['Val1'] - df['Val2'], 
                     df['Val2'] - df['Val1'])

print (df)
     Country  Val1  Val2  new
0  Australia     4     7    3
1     Bambua    23    44   21
2     Tambua    24     2   22
```